# Put PageView in PageView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a widget like this:

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      children: [
        Container(),
        PageView(
          controller: childController,
          children: [],
        ),
        Container(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The problem is that when I scroll through page2, it cannot switch to the widget that is on the page1. How to switch to widgets on page1?

Comment: Why not put `childPageView` children inside main `pageView`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh childController is PageView.builder Maybe you know how to put different widgets in PageView.builder?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your pageviews within children array like this

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PageController _tabsPageController;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _tabsPageController = PageController();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _tabsPageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children:[

           Expanded(
              child:PageView(
                controller: _tabsPageController,
                
                children:[


                  HomeTab(),
                  SearchTab(),
                  SavedTab()

                ]
              )
            ,

          ),
          
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the header and footer. And I need to flip

Comment: sorry i did not understand you could you explain it a little bit more?